# Will a 301 permanent redirect to change URLs to use only a query string with a single parameter hurt SEO?

Tags: php, html, seo

If I use a `RedirectMatch 301` code in my `.htaccess` file:

Original: `/automobiles/pickups/?category=classic`

Redirect: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/automobiles/(.*)/?$ /?s=$1 [L]`

Will it hurt my SEO status?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 2):

301 is the best redirect to use in your scenario, e.g. permanent redirect. I could speculate there is a very slight deterioration of link value passed through 301, so it's best if you could update the original links to point to their new destination. It won't hurt if you don't get everyone else to update external links. Although definitely update internal links to point to the new url.

Edit:

I normally used RewriteRule instead of RedirectMatch 301.

`RewriteRule ^/automobiles/pickups/([a-z-]+)$ /automobiles/pickups/?category=$1 [R=301,L]`

Rewrites your URL `/automobiles/pickups/?category=classic` to  `/automobiles/pickups/classic`

Use Firefox LiveHeaders to make sure visiting `/automobiles/pickups/?category=classic` will return a 301 to `/automobiles/pickups/classic` and also change all your internal links to point to /automobiles/pickups/classic

Answer (score 1):

SEO redirection, From bad to good :

- Javascript
- Meta
- htaccess redirect
- htaccess rewrite

If you can, use rewrite instead of redirect.  Apparently, redirect 301 is not so bad, however, since nobody really knows the robot's criteria then the best is to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

**No, It will not affect your website SEO. If you are using 301 permanent redirection technique.**

A 301 redirect is the most efficient and Search Engine Friendly method for webpage redirection. It’s not that hard to implement and it should preserve your search engine rankings for that particular page. If you have to change file names or move pages around, it’s the safest option. The code “301” is interpreted as “moved permanently”.